# Parse XML Web Service Response in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, soap, xml-parsing

I need to parse the response XML message from Web Service. 
The message is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><HelloAppleResponse xmlns="http://testest.org/"><HelloAppleResult>StringThatINeed</HelloAppleResult></HelloAppleResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Message is in a variable call strData:

```
var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

I need to use NSXMLParser, but I don't know how to use it.

```
    // NSXMLParserDelegate

  func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: NSDictionary!) {
        currentElementName = elementName
    }


func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {
    if currentElementName == "HelloAppleResult" {
        txtResult.text = string
    }
}
```

Comment: Lookup NSXMLParser ...

Comment: I don't use Swift nor I develop for ios, but I think that this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195136/parsing-hierarchical-xml-in-swift-using-nsxmlparser

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, i know that. Can you give me the piece of code adapted to my request, please? 'Cause I tried several times without success. =(

Comment: *"Yeah, i know that."* – That is not apparent from your question. Show what you tried and where the problems are, and then we can help.

Comment: @MartinR Ok, post edited.